# Using <section> to group sample content in home page (e.g. "Portfolio", "About")

Tags: html, seo, semantics

Will it be semantically correct to wrap sample content (small preview content) in `<section>` tags when it is presented in a homepage? Also is it a good idea to use it for banners or big areas of a page? I have read the definition, but still struggle to understand it. When should we use a section tag, is it at all necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO:

1. Yes. `<section>` should contain content that may have its own header and is semantically connected with each other. Preview of the content (e.g. title and one paragraph of article on articles list) meets this definition.
2. No, use `<div>` instead. `<section>` is absolutely not a generic container element.

See more on http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/

Answer (score 0):

I think yes. `<section>` will be appropriate to contains the part between the <`header>` and `<footer>`.
Just remeber that W3C requirements say that a `<section>` should have at least one headline (h1 to h6) inside.
In fact `<section>` are for the "master ".
For smaller content you can use `<article>`.

Comment: W3C HTML5 drafts do *not* require heading elements inside `section`; they just say (right now): “The theme of each section should be identified, typically by including a heading (h1-h6 element) as a child of the section element.” Note the word “should” as opposite to “shall” and the use of the word “typically”.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake !